# Can I use autossh for gcloud compute ssh?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud, autossh

For some reason `ssh` doesn't work to set up a tunnel to my Google Compute Engine instance. I have to use `gcloud compute ssh`. I'd really like to set up a persistent/resilient tunnel, like one gets with [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/). Is there any way I can do so using `gcloud compute ssh`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcloud compute ssh` simply copies your ssh key to the project `sshKeys` metadata (see **Cloud Console > Compute Engine > Metadata > SSH Keys**) and runs standalone SSH with the `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` key. To see the exact command line invoked, run `gcloud compute ssh --dry-run ...`. Anything that's possible with typical SSH is possible with `gcloud compute ssh`.

Another option to investigate is [`gcloud compute config-ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh), which syncs your `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` SSH key to the project and sets up your `~/.ssh/config` file so that you can run `ssh` without `gcloud`.

Comment: Note that `gcloud compute config-ssh` only works for instances with public IPs, i.e. it's N/A for those of us who rely on IAP (Identity Aware Proxy).

Regarding `--dry-run` - it's pretty neat, just note when used with IAP the command it outputs can't be used verbatim as it's missing quotes and "=" in `ProxyCommand` (at least as of gcloud version 283.0.0)

Should anyone encounter this, the syntax printed is `-o ProxyCommand /usr/bin/python3 -S ... -o ...` while it should be `-o ProxyCommand="/usr/bin/python3 -S ..." -o ...`